# MySQL REPLACE rows WHERE field a equals x and field b equals y

Tags: php, mysql, replace, where-clause

I'm trying to construct a 'new comments' feature where the user is shown the number of new comments since the last visit.
I've constructed a 'Views' table that contains the topic id, the user id and a timestamp.  What's the best way of updating the timestamp every time the user visits that topic or inserting a fresh row if one doesn't exist?  At the moment I have:

```
REPLACE INTO Views (MemberID, TopicID, Visited)
SET ('$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]', '$threadid', '$t')
WHERE MemberID = $_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID] AND TopicID = $threadid
```

However, this does not work.  Is it possible to do this in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `SET` with `VALUES`. The syntax is:

```
REPLACE [LOW_PRIORITY | DELAYED]
  [INTO] tbl_name [(col_name,...)]
  {VALUES | VALUE} ({expr | DEFAULT},...),(...),...
```

**Edit:** Note that this only really works if you have set `MemberID` and `TopicID` as a unique key in your table. If you do this, then you should just be able to do either:

```
REPLACE INTO Views (MemberID, TopicID, Visited)
VALUES ('$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]', '$threadid', '$t')
```

or

```
INSERT INTO Views (MemberID, TopicID, Visited)
VALUES ('$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]', '$threadid', '$t')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Visited = '$t'
```

(of course, you should be using proper placeholders so Little Bobby Tables doesn't make a visit and destroy your database)

Comment: I tried the second one and it just keeps adding rows instead of replacing.  I also tried "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MemberID = '$_SESSION[SESS_MEMBER_ID]', TopicID = '$threadid'".

Comment: @Miles: You need to have set those two up as a combined unique key on your table first. Then, if you try to insert a row that has the same unique key, it'll update the value of `Visited` instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way with only one query, but you could try this:

```
<?php
$where = "where `MemberID`=".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']." and `TopicID`=".$threadid;
if( mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query( "select * from `Views` ".$where)))
   mysql_query( "update `Views` set `Visited`='".$t."' ".$where);
else
   mysql_query( "insert into `Views` (`MemberID`, `TopicID`, `Visited`) values ('".$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']."', '".$threadid."', '".$t."')");
?>
```

That would run two queries total.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, it will update itself automatically every time the row is altered. So just call update on the row (if it exists, otherwise create it) and change just the topicId. The database will handle changing the time.

Really, I wouldn't use REPLACE. Instead, maybe you could create a stored procedure that checks to see if the row exists (just pass the memberId and topicId) and creates it if not, and then returns the timestamp to you. This makes more sense.

And using a stored proc means only one trip to the DB.

Comment: So you're saying it's best to have more than one query, one that checks to see if it exists then one that updates if it does and inserts if it doesn't?  I could do this with an if... else but I thought it would be more efficient if there was a way to do it in one query